# Is there a name for approximation algorithms with $f(OPT)$ approximation factor?

Tags: approximation-algorithms

I have read that there are approximation algorithms with two different kinds of approximation factors:

- $c$ . A constant approximation factor.
- $f(n)$ . An approximation factor that is function of the input size.

However, right know I'm dealing with an approximation factor of the following nature:

- $f(OPT)$ . Namely, an approximation factor that is a function of the optimal solution size.

Is there an special name for this kind of approximation algorithms?

Comment: This type of ratio has been described in a number of recent papers, see for example [Marx'08](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rrw/presentations/marx-approx.pdf) and [CCKLMNT'17](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.04218.pdf). The latter, more recent paper refers to this as a Fixed Parameter Approximation Algorithm, or FPT-Approximation.

Comment: This is common for geometric set cover problems. There is no special name for it, because ultimately opt might be $\Theta(n)$, so people are not convinced by the importance of such cases.